# Split string after certain character

Tags: python, split

I have this line of code in my python file:

```
included_users = os.environ["INCLUDED_USERS"]
```

where in one of my config files I have:

```
INCLUDED_USERS = fname.lname:UDWADAW,fname2.lname2:DADWAD,fname3.lname3:DWAFUD,etc.
```

How can I make it so that I filter the INCLUDED_USERS list to append to an array with just the strings after ":" ?

so for example I want from the INCLUDED_USERS list:

```
INCLUDED_USERS_ID = ["UDWADAW,DADWAD,DWAFUD"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Split on commas to get a list of name:value pairs, then split each pair on a colon.

```
for pair in included_users.split(","):
    value = pair.split(":")[1]
    INCLUDED_USERS_ID.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension, but you need to convert included_user to string.

```
INCLUDED_USERS = "fname.lname:UDWADAW,fname2.lname2:DADWAD,fname3.lname3:DWAFUD"
INCLUDED_USERS_ID = [ i.split(':')[1]   for i in INCLUDED_USERS.split(',')]
print(INCLUDED_USERS_ID)
```

Output of the above code is

```
['UDWADAW', 'DADWAD', 'DWAFUD']
```

Hope this helps your case, if not please feel free to comment. Thansks